# How does the Japanese language do dual quantification?

Tags: quantifiers

According to the evolution of the English language, certain quantifiers (both, either, neither, each I think this is exhaustive) are remnant of the older dual number.

However, Japanese, if I recall *her* linguistic evolution correctly, never had a dual number. So how do Japanese language speakers quantify over dual elements? That is, what is the idiomatic Japanese version of usage of both, either, neither, and each?

Comment: _Both_ is possibly a remnant of a pre-Proto-Germanic dual, but that’s only diachronically relevant – the dual has been lost for millennia and has no influence on Modern English at all. _Either_ and _neither_ are not duals at all (except to the extent that the comparative rather than the superlative tends to be used when only two elements are compared). Japanese doesn’t really have grammatical number at all. But you don’t need to have an actual dual number in order to have specific phrases and constructions for dealing with pairs of two.

Comment: Japanese referred to as *her*?? What do you mean by dual number? Anyway, this forum is for linguistics, not translation.

Comment: @Lambie PIE [\*dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s) had feminine gender, and it remained feminine gender in Latin *lingua*, Old English *tunge* :) .

Comment: @Arfrever In English, the pronoun is it regardless.

Comment: Also note that Japanese usually does not use distinct positive and negative pronouns/whatever (like *either* versus *neither*, *everybody* versus *nobody*, *always* versus *never*). For negated meaning, verb itself should be negated. E.g. 「私は[いつも](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/いつも)肉を[食べない](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/食べる)。」 = "I always do not eat meat." = "I never eat meat." (食べる = "eat", 食べない = "eat.NEG")

Comment: This belongs on the Japanese stack.

Comment: @Lambie In the King's English, languages and nationalities are usually referred to by the feminine gender. It's just an old English convention; a long forgotten convention before political correctness.

Comment: @HolyKnowing You must be kidding. In all my born days, I have never ever seen a language referred to by her or him.

Comment: @Lambie Vladimir Nabokov refers to French the language by "her" in his novel *Lolita*. I can't find the full excerpt, but ChatGPT3.5 says that it happens around this passage: ""French, of course, is the only language that can possibly convey the passion, the heaven-sent, hell-bent, shattering, ludicrous quality of the extra-terrestrial phenomenon known as amour.""

Comment: @HolyKnowing Hahaha  Nabokov is a literary writer. In literary writing, you can basically do as you like.

Comment: This post was already asked here and answered (and referred to the Linguistics SE one). https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/101410/how-does-the-japanese-language-quantify-over-dual-numbers